# Can velocity be defined as the rate of change of displacement and the rate of change of position?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differentiation

Can we have velocity = $\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \dfrac{dr}{dt} = v(t)$? Can we define as they should be the same in any frame of reference, say we have any $1$ Dimensional frame $F_1$, we will have a particle moving in a frame and position $r(t)$, the displacement will be $s(t)r(t)+r_0$
and therefore $\dfrac{ds}{dt} = r(t)+\dfrac{dr_0}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dr_0}{dt}=0$ therefore $\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \dfrac{dr}{dt}$

Comment: What makes you think that we cannot ?

Comment: This is correct just for 1 dimensional frame but not in general

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, no. Velocity is a vector. Rate of change of x is a scalar, so to possibly be a velocity, one has to multiply the scalar by the corresponding unit vector, thus converting x position to displacement from the origin along the x-axis, $x \hat x$. At that point, if displacement from the origin along the x-axis is parallel to the displacement vector, velocity is equal to the rate of change of that vector, else it is not. (Consider an object traveling in the $\hat y$ direction - it has nonzero velocity, but $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$.)

Mathematically,

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} \hat x = \vec v(t) \iff \dfrac{d\vec s}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dt}\hat x \iff \vec s \parallel \hat x$

Since you are taking movement only along one dimension, $\vec s \parallel \hat x$ is guaranteed, so all you need to do to convert the rate of change of position to the rate of change of displacement is to multiply by the corresponding unit vector $\hat x$.

Comment: $x$ is a vector, $s$ is also a vector, the derivative of $x$ should be a vector, think of position as being a vector quantity, I gave a bad example I should have labeled position as $r$ not x.

Answer (score 0):

Going from position $\vec r_1$ to position $\vec r_2$ represents a change of position equal to $\,\vec r_2-\vec r_1$ and this is the displacement.

Thus rate of change of position is the same as rate of change of displacement.